# Named piped for STDIN to control movie player

Tags: shell, named-pipes

I had this working, but for the life of me I can no longer figure out why I can't use this named pipe to control a movie player (ie. `mplayer`, `vlc`, `omxplayer`...) via commands from different local terminals.

**Terminal/ssh session 1:**

```
user@computer1$ mkfifo /path/of/pipe
user@computer1$ tail -f /dev/null > /path/of/pipe
```

**Terminal/ssh session 2:**

```
user@computer1$ cat /path/of/pipe | {mplayer,vlc,omxplayer} /path/of/video
```

**Terminal/ssh session 3:**

```
user@computer1$ echo -n q > /path/of/pipe
```

Comment: it works for `mplayer`. It doesn't work for `vlc` on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what had changed was not the command(s), but something about the pipe. My guess is that I issued a `tail -f /dev/null > /path/of/pipe` which did not close for some reason. Once I deleted the pipe and created it again (or used a different pipe), the problem went away.